# Build Cocoa Touch Framework with dependencies added externally

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios-frameworks

I have created a Cocoa-Touch-Framework (let's call it MyFmk) which uses a third party framework(call it thirdPartyFmk) as a dependency.

Currently I am using the third party framework by adding it in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section in Xcode. It builds fine, and my app that uses MyFmk builds properly and does what it intends to do.

But I don't want to build MyFmk with thirdPartyFmk inside it. I want my app to include both MyFmk and thirdPartyFmk as it's dependencies. Currently I am not able to do that. How can I compile MyFmk without adding thirdPartyFmk into `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section?

Basically, what I want to do is [this](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#pure-framework-build-no-third-party-libraries-included--library-source-distribution), as mentioned in the article's "How do I include Third-Party Libraries in my Framework" section

Googling this did not yield any result, so I am not sure this is already asked.

PS: I cannot build MyFmk using cocoapods since I don't want the .m files to be visible

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a lot of `Build Phases` detail work to make this happen.

Your application looks like this:

- `MyApplication.app`

  - `MyFramework.framework`

    - `ThirdParty.framework`

In `MyFramework.framework` make sure that `ThirdParty.framework` is in the `Target Dependencies` `Build Phase` of the `MyApplication.app` target and that `MyApplication.app` depends on `MyFramework.framework`. This will assure that everything gets refreshed at build time.

In `MyApplication.app` target, you'll need to add both `MyFramework.framework` and `ThirdParty.framework` to the `Copy Frameworks` `Build Phase`.

Finally, make sure that `MyFramework.framework` has the correct `Runtime Search Path` either `@executable_path/../Frameworks` on `macOS` or `@executable_path/Frameworks` on `iOS` so that it can find `ThridParty.framework` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ive tried this, but the resulting framework that is generated contains both myfmk and thirdparty.fmk. I know this since I tried dropping myfmk into a  totally different application, where it worked entirely even without importing thirdpartyfmk. That shouldn't happen right?

Comment: Btw I had to  third-party fmk in the linked libraries section after performing the above steps otherwise the linker error would not go away

Comment: You may need to remove `ThirdParrty.framework` from the `Embedded Libraries` on the `General` pane of the inspector.

Comment: The debugger fixes up execution and library load paths when you run the app in Xcode, which sometimes makes things confusing when distributing the app.

Comment: I tried this. But the result seems to be the same though. I can still build by dropping myfmk into a different application, where it worked without importing thirdpartyfmk